# What's the name of the instrumental music played when Yato releases Hiro in Noragami Aragoto Episode 13?

Tags: noragami

Could you please name the song? My friend wants that song. Help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you're still looking for the answer but that song is called 夜卜譚 ("Yatotan"). It's the 13th song of the Noragami Aragoto soundtrack.